# Pass Reset - No route matches [PATCH] "/password_resets.SOLceKJXoax55zSBAfAhTQ"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the Michael Hartl rails tutorial and trying to implement the password reset functionality but the request that sends the password reset form (The form where you reset your password) looks like /password_resets.SOLceKJXoax55zSBAfAhTQ which rails then says: No route matches [PATCH] "/password_resets.SOLceKJXoax55zSBAfAhTQ"  In the tutorial we are asked to use this route: resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]   But I get that error message.

This is how my password_resets_controller.rb update method looks like:

```
def update
    if password_blank?
      flash.now[:danger] = "Password can't be blank"
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Any idea how does my method or my route is causing that error?
Thank you in advance.

Update:
Adding my Reset Password view (password_resets\edit.html.erb)

```
 <% provide(:title, 'Reset Password') %>
 <h1>Reset Password</h1>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <%= form_for(@user, url: password_resets_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :uemail, @user.uemail %>

 <%= f.label :password %>
 <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "confirmation" %>
 <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.submit "update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a typo somewhere and it should be `/password_resets/SOLceKJXoax55zSBAfAhTQ`.  Can you post the view code that renders the form?

Comment: Please show us the route, probably `password_reset_path(params[:id])` will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: password_resets_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
```

Comment: This was it. I can't believe such silly type was the cause of hours of looking around at routes and other parts of the code. Thank you so much.